# how to get the previous form object using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have two individual form tag as bellow.

1st Form :-

```
 <form class="threadform threadright">
   <textarea class="simpleta required" name="Body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-inverse btn-small" />
   <input type="hidden" name="ParentId" value="@comment.Id"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="VehicleId" value="@Model.VehicleId"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="AttachedThumbnailUrl" id="AttachedThumbnailUrl" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="AttachedImageUrl" id="AttachedImageUrl" value="" />
   <input type="hidden" name="IsCommentHaveImage" id="IsCommentHaveImage" value="0" />
   <div class="feedback"></div>
   <img src="" class="imgpreview" height="169px" width="300px" />
   <img class="closepiccomment" style="cursor: pointer;" src="" />
</form>
```

2nd form

```
<form>
 <input accept="image/*" type="file" class="fileuploadimg" />
 <br />
 <input type="hidden" class="picommenturl" value="" />
 <button type="reset" class="resetbutton" style="display: none"></button>
</form>
```

now when i select the any file i call the function and in that i want to access the previous form > img tag and want to set src attribute.

Comment: Set the src attribute to what?

Comment: Where is your attempt to resolve it???

Comment: Got the answer $(this).parents('form:first').prev()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a value of the image, try this:

```
$('.threadform').find('img.imgpreview').attr('src', 'new_value_here');
```

Using this code you will get to the `.threadform` form, and in it the code will find the `img.imgpreview` which is the image with the className of imgpreview, and then after this, it will change the attribute of the image, which attr? `src` attribute, and the new value would be the value in the second parameter.

Comment: its apply for all the who have the "threadform" class. but i want to apply for the particular selected <input accept="image/*" type="file" class="fileuploadimg" /> parent form object

Comment: Then try this: `$(this.form)` to select the current form only. Or try using some match of the classNames or Ids ...

Comment: to get the previous form of $(this.form) ?